# Checkbox is not getting clicked properly in testproject or andriod app

Tags: checkbox, click, test-project, testproject.io

i have an android app where it has 3 checkboxes in a view. All three controls are of type andriod.widget.checkbox. Along with these checkboxes there is a text content as well. Inside that text content, there is a link also. Now my aim is to click on that checkboxes. But when i click on the checkbox with testproject recording on, for one checkbox it is not getting checked though it is getting clicked and for the other two checkboxes, the link inside the checkbox is getting clicked and link is getting opened. Since it is a single view component, i could not differentiate between checkbox  and the text. i have attached the testproject element explorer view and the screen view.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you need to tap on a specific part of a mobile element (both Android or iOS), you can use the Tap element at relative point action.

You can hover the wrapper element of the element you want to tap on, double shift to capture it, and select the “Tap at relative point” action, by providing the Horizontal tap percentage and the Vertical tap percentage (notice: it starts from the top-left corner of the element) you will be able to tap on a specific point on the wrapper element.

Here you can read more about it and find an example [here](https://docs.testproject.io/testproject-addons/available-addons/element-extensions-addon).